# GridView LinkButton OnClientClick. Why the second parameter is coming as Undefined?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

Hi I have below code and I am calling View_Date Javascript function on LinkButton click. The OverwriteType is coming as UnDefined?

```
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="keyId"  HeaderText="Key"  />
<asp:BoundField DataField="keyIdValue"  HeaderText="value" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="overWriteType"  HeaderText="Overwrite" Visible="false" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Overwrite" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
<ItemTemplate>
<itemstyle width="5%" />
<asp:LinkButton CssClass="l_link"  ID="lnkView" runat="server"  
DataTextField="overWriteType" 
CommandName="overWriteType"
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("overWriteType") %>'  Text='<%# Eval("overWriteType") %>' 
OnClientClick='<%#string.Format("return view_Data(\"{0},{1}\");", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "keyId"), DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "overWriteType")) %>' 

                                                                            >
</asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This is the Javascript function.

```
 function view_Data(keyId, overWriteType) {
                alert(overWriteType);  //This value is undefined
                var podUrl = shipList.options[shipList.selectedIndex].value;
                window.open("OverwriteConfiguration.aspx?KeyId=" + keyId + "&podURL=" + podUrl + "&overWriteType=" + overWriteType, 'ViewChange',
          'height=540,width=750,left=150,top=150,screenX=0,screenY=100');

                return false;
            }
```

the value of OverWriteType parameter to the Javascript is coming as Undefined.
What am i doing wrong?

Inspect Element is showing value as below:

```
<a onclick="return view_Data("BIOMETRIC.Post.TaskCount,Pod");" id="gvPodKeyValues_lnkView_3" class="l_link" datatextfield="overWriteType" href="javascript:__doPostBack('gvPodKeyValues$ctl05$lnkView','')">Pod</a>
```

Appreciate your responses.
Thanks

Comment: you can right click the button in the browser (ie Chrome), and choose 'Inspect element', then you could see how the function is called, you can use/give us that feedback to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You are joining the two parameters in one because of the quotes, instead of this

```
OnClientClick='<%#string.Format("return view_Data(\"{0},{1}\");", 
                      DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "keyId"), 
                      DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "overWriteType")) %>'
```

write this

```
OnClientClick='<%#string.Format("return view_Data('{0}','{1}');", 
                      DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "keyId"), 
                      DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "overWriteType")) %>'
```

then you don't need to escape the quotes and now you have your two params